# Where in PHPStorm I can change align for commented block option?

Tags: phpstorm, psr-12

When in in PHPStorm 2021.1 I comment some part of code “//” chars are left aligned, like

```
//        foreach ($categories as $category) {
//            $retArray[] = [
//                'id' => $category->id,
//                'title' => $category->snippet->title,
//                'channelId' => $category->snippet->channelId
//            ];
//        };
```

When I apply pint (with psr12 set) left margings are set for “//” chars

```
  //        foreach ($categories as $category) {
  //            $retArray[] = [
  //                'id' => $category->id,
  //                'title' => $category->snippet->title,
  //                'channelId' => $category->snippet->channelId
  //            ];
  //        };
```

It seems to for that pint works ok. Where in PHPStorm I can change this option ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently, "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP > Code Generation > Comment code > Line comment at first column" is the option that you are looking for. Also, you may configure Laravel Pint as an external formatter in IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-laravel-pint.html#fix-issues-with-code-reformat